# Discussion Board - SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online

How to categories the discussion board into travelling , food to eat and other stuff so if  people will click travelling they can see thread related to travelling and and they are able to reply it.
 keeping this in mind i created a view and categorize it . but now if i m clicking a question to give my inputs in i cant reply !
 Wat should i do ? Should i create 4 different types of discussion board like one for travelling and 3 others and import the default view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to handle this (if I understand the question correctly) is to have tags. You could have messages tagged "travel", "food", "expenses", and "hotels" (for example). The convenient thing about using tags is that one messaage can have several tags (like Stack Exchange messages). That way, if someone wants to discuss hotel expenses, the message could have both tags.

Comment: I'm new to SharePoint online . How to add tags in  discussion board ?

Comment: Having just checked: the out-of-the-box Discussion web part does not support tags. Because of that, may I suggest that instead, you consider embedding a Yammer group on the page?

I apologize for the confusion. I'm used to more sophisticated discussion boards. It seems that Microsoft decided that their resources should be devoted to Yammer instead of a SharePoint feature.

Comment: In SharePoint online there is a web part for yammer !! i wanted the discussion board to be categorize . Do you know any other ways to do it ????